# Final field inheritance in java

Tags: java, inheritance, field, final

Is it possible to have a given subclass initialize static final fields in its superclass?  Essentially I would like for the subclass to configure required class-wide variables.  Unfortunately, the abstract keyword doesn't exactly work with fields..

Comment: static fields??? inheritance???

Comment: I guess I'd simply like to avoid code duplication by requiring subclasses to declare given fields.  These variables aren't to be allocated with each instance, because that doesn't make sense in this case (maxHealth, maxEnergy, etc.)

Answer (score 5):

No - how would you expect it to work if there were *two* subclasses which tried to do the same thing? If you've got static final fields, they must be initialized by the class which declares them.

If you're trying to use static fields and inheritance together, that's *usually* a sign that something's wrong to start with, to be honest - they're two concepts which generally don't play well together. People often try to "fake" inheritance with static methods etc, and it usually ends badly - this sounds like a variation on that theme.

If you can describe your broader picture, we may be able to help you more. I would urge you to avoid statics *in general* for the sake of testability, by the way. They're fine for genuine constants, but if it's anything like configuration, it's nicer to pass in relevant settings when constructing an object (IMO).

EDIT: I can see four options which would model your situation better:

1. Use annotations: see True Soft's answer
2. Make `maxHealth` a *method*, so you can ask any player what their maximum health is - that's then polymorphic, so can be overridden in each class
3. Model `Player` and `PlayerClass` separately:

   ```
   public class Player {
       private final PlayerClass playerClass;
       private int health; // etc
   }

   public class PlayerClass {
       private final int maxHealth; //etc
   }
   ```

   That way you *can* have inheritance at the "player class" level, but you don't have to - you could create several `PlayerClass` instances which *behave* the same way, but have different stats... or you could subclass `PlayerClass` to give custom behaviour. At that point you may not need different subclasses of `Player` at all.
4. The same as idea 3, but using an enum:

   ```
   public enum PlayerClass {
       ELF(10), DWARF(9), HUMAN(5);

       private final int maxHealth;
       private PlayerClass(int maxHealth) {
           this.maxHealth = maxHealth;
       }
   }
   ```

Personally my preference would be the final option, I suspect. You can *still* override behaviour, but you have a fixed set of possible classes - which probably models your game reasonably accurately.

Comment: > No - how would you expect it to work if there were 
> two subclasses which tried to do the same thing? If 
> you've got static final fields, they must be 
initialized by the class which declares them."

Ahhh of course.  Basically what I'm trying to do is implement a class system on a game I'm working on.  Each player can have a class, and each class should have different attributes. (Speed, health, etc.)

Comment: But I don't feel like every instance of the class should be allocating the maxHealth, maxEnergy etc. every time.

Comment: I'm walking at the moment but will reply in a while.

Comment: I'm realizing now that my initial question was moderately stupid. They shouldn't be static to the superclass given that they should change between classes.. I've found the easiest way is to keep them final, but pass values in through the constructor. (super())  Sorry about that D:

Comment: @user984799: But if they're *only* available on instances, but always the same for instances of the same class, it feels like you may be modelling things slightly badly - see my answer for a separation of "player class" from "player".

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Jon Skeet's  answer, I don't think it's that bad  "If you're trying to use static fields and inheritance together". I suggest you to use annotations:

```
@Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@interface AValue {
    /**
     * @return something final that is "static" (attached to a class), 
     * but also "abstract" (looks that it be changed in the subclasses)
     */
    String value();
}

@AValue("A default value") // you can ommit this, but all subclasses should add the annotation (so the method from Utils work OK)
abstract class A { }

@AValue("Value for class B")
class B extends A { }

@AValue("Value for class C")
class C extends A { }

class Utils {
    static String getValueOfClass(Class<? extends A> clazz) {
        return clazz.getAnnotation(AValue.class).value();
    }
}
```

Comment: So you've suggested something which *isn't* static fields... that's fine, but in what way does that go against my recommendation not to use static fields?

Comment: It isn't static, but it behaves like a static field (the value is for a class, not for an instance)

Comment: I wouldn't regard that as trying to use static fields and inheritance together - certainly not in the way that the OP was. I still think it's nicer to separate the "player" data from the "class of player" data, to be honest. No need for reflection, no chance of a subclass that fails to declare the annotation, etc.

Comment: At the time I answered this question, the OP did not already give the details of what he was trying to do. Maybe my solution is not the best in his case, but in other cases I think it is perfect.